# partial differential equations, Laplace equation, boundary conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, boundary-value-problem

For the stated problem I got the following equations after applying separation of variables, I am confused as to how to apply the mentioned boundary conditions to this problem :

\begin{align}
G''(x)+(4\pi^2-c)G(x)&=0\\
4H''(y)+cH(y)&=0
\end{align}

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the first part...I'm calling $c$ lambda $\lambda$

$$ G^{''}(x)  + (4\pi^{2} - \lambda )G(x) = 0 \tag{1}  $$

call $4\pi^{2} - \lambda = \alpha $

$$ G^{''}(x)  + \alpha G(x) = 0 \tag{2}  $$

$$ G(x) = c_{1} \cos(\sqrt{\alpha}x) + c_{2}\sin(\sqrt{\alpha}x) \tag{3} $$

the x boundaries are neumann

$$ \frac{\partial }{\partial x}G(x) = -\sqrt{\alpha}c_{1}\sin(\sqrt{\alpha}x) + \sqrt{\alpha}c_{2}\cos(\sqrt{\alpha}x) \tag{4} $$

put in $x=0$ and $c_{2} =0$

$$ \frac{\partial }{\partial x}G(0) =  \sqrt{\alpha}c_{2}  = 0\tag{5} $$

now $G(x) = c_{1}\cos(\sqrt{\alpha}x) $

$$ \frac{\partial }{\partial x}G(1) = -\sqrt{\alpha}c_{1}\sin(\sqrt{\alpha}1) = \sin(\sqrt{\alpha})   \tag{6} $$

in order to determine the eigenvalues, is this good? Can you apply the $y$ boundaries now?

Note for the next one you have

$$ H^{''}(y) + \frac{\lambda}{4}H(y) = 0 \tag{7} $$

however, the eigenvalues are going to be related now

### Edit

If you simply solve the above on line $6$ and we let the boundary actually be $L$

$$\sin(\sqrt{\alpha}L) = 0 \implies \sqrt{\alpha}L = n\pi \implies \sqrt{\alpha} = \frac{n\pi}{L} \tag{8} $$

now remember what $\alpha$ is

$$ \sqrt{\alpha} = \sqrt{4\pi^{2} - \lambda}  =\frac{n\pi}{L} \tag{9}   $$

now $L =1$

$$4\pi^{2} - \lambda  =n^{2}\pi^{2} \tag{10}$$

$$ - \lambda = n^{2}\pi^{2} - 4\pi^{2}  \implies \lambda = 4\pi^{2} - n^{2}\pi^{2} \tag{11}$$

Comment: for the y boundaries, the solution of H(y) will have sin hyperbolic and cos hyperbolic functions?

Comment: and i got the corresponding eigenfunction for G(x) as: Gn(x)=cos(n*pi*x)

Comment: I didn't realize it was non-homogeneous at first.. you have to do something about that

Comment: you should check how many eigenvalues you have.